# Applying Wiener-Khinchin theorem on a slightly complicated messy wave.

Tags: fourier-transform, noise

Assume I have a wave of the form

$$f(t) = e^{-i(\omega t + \phi(t))}$$

and the same wave after a time delay $\tau = \tau(t)$

$$f(t) = e^{-i(\omega t + \phi(t + \tau(t))}$$

Assume $\tau(t) =  \tau_{0} \left(1+ c \sin(\omega_{0}t)\right)$

Usually when applying Wiener-Khinchin theorem, the auto correlation is taken between $f(t)$ and $f(t+\tau)$

$$R(\tau) = \langle f(t+\tau) f(t)^{*}\rangle$$
where $\tau$ is assumed to be constant.  My objective is to attack a physics problem where solving this integral becomes important.  Usually applying Wiener-Khinchin theorem on a wave, gives its power spectrum.  In my problem, the delay time itself a function of time, I don't know whether Wiener-Khinchin theorem itself can be applied in the first place.  Any suggestion on how to find the auto-correlation is appreciable.

Assume $\phi(t)$ is a Wiener process or Brown noise. In general, if $\tau$ is a constant, then $\phi(t+\tau) - \phi(t) = \Delta$, where $\Delta$ has a Gaussian distribution of the form

$$g(\Delta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\Delta^2/{2\sigma^2}}$$.

For a Wiener process, $\sigma^2 = \vert\tau\vert$.

Comment: Norbert W[ie](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norbert_Wiener)ner please.

Comment: Firstly, note that the delayed wavefunction is given by 
$
f(t+\tau) = e^{-i\omega(t+\tau)-i\phi(t+\tau)} \neq e^{-i\omega t-i\phi(t+\tau)}.
$
Now, if $\tau$ is time-dependent, Wiener-Khinchin theorem cannot be applied straightforwardly, because it is based on the properties of the Fourier transform, where the quantity $\tau$ is assumed to be constant (see e.g. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wiener-KhinchinTheorem.html). Perhaps you may derive a generalized version of it for particular functions $\phi$ and $\tau$.